# Python - BeautifulSoup can't match a tag with specific text (using re.compile)

Tags: python, beautifulsoup

I need to access to the string 'My site', but this simple regex can't match the p tag:

```
data = """<p>Site: <a href="www.example.com" style="font-weight: 100;">My site</a></p>"""
soup = BeautifulSoup(data, 'lxml')
site = soup.find('p', text = re.compile('Site: '))
print site
>> None
```

If I try with:

```
data = """<p>Site: <a href="www.example.com" style="font-weight: 100;">My site</a></p>"""
soup = BeautifulSoup(data, 'lxml')
site = soup.findAll('p')
print site
>> [<p>Site: <a href="www.example.com" style="font-weight: 100;">My site</a></p>]
```

it works. Of course this tag is on a page with various p tags so I don't want to access it by index.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can iterate through all `p` tags and see if each of them has `'Site'` in it:

```
for p in soup.findAll('p'):
    if(re.match('(Site)', p.text):
        print (p.text) # Site: My site
```